# Tracking Social Button Clicks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, social-networking

On a website, I have some social buttons (tweet, facebook like, google+1, ..). Most of them are inserted using an iframe.

The task is to track use interaction with those buttons: if someone +1'ed the content - and AJAX request should update my local statistics on the server.

However, with JS I can't access the contents of the iframe due to security restrictions: can't bind 'click' event.

How do I track clicks on those social buttons, then?

---

Possible solutions:

1. Bind 'click' to the iframe object itself: it does not work.
2. Add buttons inline, w/o an iframe. No go: I should also display the number of likes for every button.
3. Try to use Social Service APIs to insert without an iframe. Not all services support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the social buttons from the main companies enable your Javascript to detect when the button has been pressed. They usually do this via Javascript events.

In other words, they'll tell your code that they've been pressed, you don't have to detect it on your own.

**Twitter**

[info on their javascript events](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events)

**Facebook**

You need to use the XFBML version of the button. From the Facebook Like button [FAQ](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

> > How do I know when a user clicks a Like button?
> >
> > If you are using the XFBML version of the button, you can subscribe to the 'edge.create' event through [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).

**Google +1**

See the `callback` parameter in their docs. See section [+1 Tag Attributes](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plusonetag-parameters). You provide a Javascript (JS) function to their button. Your JS is then called by them when the button is pushed. Easy!

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If you could catch clicks on them you could also trigger clicks on them which would be pretty bad (imagine porn sites making you "like" them automatically).

The only thing you can do is using the APIs of the various sites to retrieve the number of people who liked/+1'd/etc. your site.